Flaky speedometer on 1998 volvo s70 - but works perfectly with spare wheel on front left
Unlike this similar sounding issue, I discovered that my speedo works 100% perfectly when the front wheel is replaced by the spare wheel (from under the floor in the trunk) - a discovery that was due to the pure "luck" of getting a left front flat.  However, after replacing the original wheel the speedo stopped working again.  (However, it occasionally kicks in for the first few minutes of driving on cold days).
I wondered if it might a magnet mounted on the wheel as used to be common for bicycle speedometers before the advent of GPS.  However, I could find nothing from visual inspection of both the original and spare wheel, and nothing in any online literature or diagrams.
There is a part: Vehicle Speed Sensor Part Number: 9495008 but this certainly doesn't attach to the wheel.
Seems, in theory, that it should be easy to fix because the wheel change does make the speedo work, but in practice, I'm at a dead end.
Other info:  The ABS light has been permanently on for at least 10 years, while the speedo has only been flaky for about 3 years.
